# Drawing a graph from DataGridView data vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, graph, datagridview, charts

I have a DataGridView1 which contains columns "dblRend" and "datDatePrepa". I need to plot a graph using these values, but i didn't find any possible result since 2 days. I tried to store the values of the DataGridView1 to 2 arrays and bind them to the Chart but always the code crashes. Does anyone has an idea, I'm stuck in here !

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you load data into DataSet? Here is example of bind chart to database http://www.linglom.com/programming/vb-net/creating-graph-with-vb-net-part-3-data-binding-chart-to-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after passing the data from DGV to arrays.

Private Sub BTloadchart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTloadchart.Click

```
    For i = 1 To (Recherche.Rend.Length - 1)
        'Recherche.Dates(i) contains the values of datePrepa and Recherche.Rend(i) contains the values of Rend which are passed from DGV of Recherche Form
        Chart1.Series("Rend").Points.AddXY(Recherche.Dates(i).ToShortDateString, Recherche.Rend(i))
    Next
End Sub
```